# Shortcut in IntelliJ executed in other program

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, evernote

I have a problem with shortcuts on Windows 10 when I have both IntelliJ and Evernote Desktop open. When I use in IntelliJ a shortcut that also exists in Evernote, then the shortcut is not executed as expected in IntelliJ, but it switches to Evernote and the shortcut is executed there.
Has anyone already faced this issue?

Comment: What is the shortcut? Check this this is not some OS globally defined shortcut. Sometimes some programs, like graphic drivers may register global shortcuts.

Comment: It was the CONTROL + SHIFT + F, find in path in IntelliJ or find all in Evernote. Meanwhile I removed this shortcut from IntelliJ to avoid conflict, but this shouldn't happen.

Comment: which version of Evernote

Comment: I have this problem with the windows desktop version of Evernote (6.25.1.9091 )

Answer (score 0):

Evernote > Help > Keyboard shortcuts > Global > Hover over the shortcut(s) that you want to disable, *one by one*, select the `...` menu and choose Disable.